# pd.read_csv do not read a complete number

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

There’s a file in excel which I saved as .csv. While reading it with `pd.read_csv`, 15-number numbers are read as scientific notation. It doesn’t matter if I changed the type from general to number in excel and save again the csv file.

> I need the ID  163783999292 instead of 1.6378E+11.

Several things haven’t work. I have same problem for some dates which shows a four digit number instead of the date format as it is often shown in excel.

Comment: Hi Michele, have you ever try "dtype" parameter on read_csv commannd? pd.read_csv('asd.csv', header = 0,  dtype = {'numbers': str,'review': str,                                                   'money': int,'some_column': dict})

Comment: A first step would be to figure out whether the issue is on writing or on reading. If you open the CSV file in a text editor, do the offending values look right there? If theye do, can you provide a minimal example (CSV file plus Python program) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: can you share the code?then It will be easy to find out the problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, chances are that you are reading data that is already in scientific notation.  This example shows that.

**Reading integer data...**

```
sim_csv = io.StringIO(
'''n
163783999292''')

df = pd.read_csv(sim_csv)
```

**delivers a value...**

```
print(df)
              n
0  163783999292
```

**with an int64 datatype**

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   n       1 non-null      int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 136.0 bytes
```

**Reading scientific format data...**

```
sim_csv = io.StringIO(
'''n
1.6378E+11''')

df = pd.read_csv(sim_csv)
```

**delivers a value...**

```
print(df)

              n
0  1.637800e+11
```

**with a float64 datatype**

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   n       1 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 136.0 bytes
```